# Changing style of an image fails sometimes (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

Using the following code, I get the size of an image:

```
function getFileSize(img) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        url: img.src,
        method: "HEAD",
        onload: function(response) {
            response.responseHeaders.match(/Content-Length: (\d+)/);
            size = RegExp.$1;
            if (size > maxS)
                // If size > max. allowed size
                markImage(img);
            else if (img.height > maxH)
                    // If img.height > max. allowed height
                markImage(img);
        }
    }); 
}
```

As you can see, the function above calls *markImage*:

```
function markImage(img) {
    img.style.border = "7px solid #990099";
    showDialog(); // This function shows a dialog
}
```

So I want to change the style of those images matching certain conditions.

If an image matches the conditions on *getFileSize*, the dialog which is called on markImage is correctly shown. However, style is not always changed.

As far as I have been able to see, the script works perfectly when `size > maxS`, but it doesn't always work when `img.height > maxH`. Actually, if `img.height > maxH`, the script works if I refresh the website but it doesn't at the first try.

On the one hand, considering the fact that *markImage* is called *onload*, this doesn't seem to be an issue related to synchronization. In addition, the dialog is correctly shown when it has to be shown. On the other hand, I also tried to change the style by using *setAttribute* but it makes no difference. So I have no idea why is this "randomly" failing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You say the dialog **always** shows correctly but the border does not always stick?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I don't have a clue. I also tried to check the height in an other part of the code, once the image has already been loaded, and then call markImage, and that worked with a problem, but I also would like to know why doesn't the code above work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if `showDialog();` always fires correctly, then that rules out image loading and rendering delays.

Some other things that could be causing the glitch:

1. Some other CSS is overriding the CSS in `markImage()`.  Change the code to:

   ```
   img.style.setProperty ("border", "7px solid #990099", "important");
   ```
2. The page has JS that modifies or reloads the target image... Intercept, block, or cleanup after such JS as appropriate.

If `showDialog();` does **not** always fire correctly, that's a different ballgame, but you indicated that this was not the case.

If something else is going on, we can't tell without seeing the target page and maybe the whole GM script.  Link to those.

Comment: Your first suggestion -adding "important"- made the trick! Once again, thank you very much!